# React - Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a react project I have this structure:

```
<div className="App">          
  <BrowserRouter>
    <BasicLayout title={"test"}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />}></Route>
        <Route path="/impostazioni" element={<Impostazioni />} />            
      </Routes> 
    </BasicLayout>          
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

And BasicLayout is like..

```
<>
  <Header ...{props} />
  <div>
    <MenuComp ...{props} />
    <>
      Test
      {React.Children.map(children, (item: any) => {
        return item;
      })}
    </>
  </div>
</>
```

When I trigger the `navigate` [ in MenuComp .. ] I have this error:

Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with React fragment '<> </>'
Fragments is grouping a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.
Please try changing the fragments with div

```
<div>
 <Header ...{props} />
 <div>
    <MenuComp ...{props} />
    <div>
         Test
         {React.Children.map(children, (item: any) => {
                return item;
              })}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error in Nextjs 13.4. I was using .jsx files and I think  this can cause error. Convert .jsx to .js files and make it client component. This resolved my error.